# Field Extensions of Q by radicals

Tags: linear-algebra, galois-theory

Is Q(√6) = Q(√3,√2)? I understand that the degree of these field extensions comes from the degree of the minimal polynomial and (alternatively) basis of the field extension. I know that the basis of Q(√3,√2) is {1,√2,√3,√6}, so Q(√6) is contained in Q(√3,√2), but is there a way to verify (or refute) that Q(√2,√3) is contained in Q(√6)? Note: Here I am assuming these field extensions over Q (when considering basis and/or degree)

Comment: You have $dim_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{6}])=2$ whereas $dim_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}])=4$ (you need to know here that $(1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6})$ is a basis over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$).

Comment: However for some computations, you can check $\mathbf Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)=\mathbf Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Degree of extension of $\mathbb{Q{(\sqrt{6})}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $2$.($f(x)=x^2-6$ is the irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$. ) Where as the degree of extension of $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $4$. They can't be equal.